# Read file with separator a space and a semicolon

Tags: c++, file, fstream, text-parsing

I wrote this to parse a file with numbers, where the separator was just a space. My goal is to read every number of the file and store it in the corresponding index of the matrix `A`. So, the first number read, should go to `A[0][0]`, second number to `A[0][1]` and so on.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int N = 5, M = 5;
    double A[N*M];
    string fname("test_problem.txt");
    ifstream file(fname.c_str());
    for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
            file >> *(A + N*c + r);
        }
    }

    for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
        for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
            cout << *(A + N*c + r) << " ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I am trying to parse a file like this:

```
1 ;2 ;3 ;4 ;5
10 ;20 ;30 ;40 ;50
0.1 ;0.2 ;0.3 ;0.4 ;0.5
11 ;21 ;31 ;41 ;5
1 ;2 ;3 ;4 ;534
```

but it will print (thus read) garbage. What should I do?

---

EDIT

Here is my attempt in C, which also fails:

```
FILE* fp = fopen("test_problem.txt", "r");
double v = -1.0;
while (fscanf(fp, "%f ;", &v) == 1) {
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

-1 will always be printed.

Comment: All `*(A + N*c + r)` could be changed into `A[N*c + r]`.

Comment: You'll need to give a better test case to illustrate exactly what you're trying to do. As the question is currently written, I could just write a program that reads every third character in each line, which I'm guessing is not what you want.

Comment: timrau, true, but this should not be a problem. @RedRoboHood I edited with what my goal is. I think the test case is good, I want to fill the matrix with the numbers of the file.

Comment: @gsamaras The problem with the test case is that it makes it seem like every number is going to be the same width, or worse still, that every number will be exactly one character. Is that actually true?

Comment: The spaces and semi-colons in the matrix do not seem to be treated by your code. Maybe use c+=3 instead of ++c in the first (for int c) statement

Comment: You say (and in the code I also dont see something else) that you have spaces as separators, but the file you are parsing has `;` as separators

Comment: @RedRoboHood you are right. I do not know if this will be always the case. I mean the digits of the numbers might differ, I guess. I think that invalidades Laurent's acomment. tobi303, every number is separated by a space and a semicolon.

Comment: Then you have to take into account this semicolons also in your code, otherwise you are trying to interpret them as numbers and get rubbish

Comment: Exactly @tobi303! But I do not know how, that's why I am asking the question. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove semicolon before converting

```
std::string temp;
file >> temp;
std::replace( temp.begin(), temp.end(), ';', ' ');
*(A + N*c + r) =    std::stod( temp );
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to know what should I do if the last number of every line has a semicolon too? For example, the first line to be like this `1 ;2 ;3 ;4 ;5 ;` instead of this `1 ;2 ;3 ;4 ;5`.

Comment: No, I am getting `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod`

Comment: `std::string temp; do {
    file >> temp;
    temp.erase (std::remove(temp.begin(), temp.end(), ';'), temp.end());
   } while ( temp.size() == 0 );

   *(A + N*c + r) = std::stod( temp );`

Comment: You should change your test values to include semicolon at the end of lines, i will be able to use modified code in my answer then

Comment: Your semicolon at the end has a space beforehand, so will be read into the `temp` `string` separately: you could use `if (temp == ";") continue;` before the `replace` to ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your C example:

```
warning: format ‘%f’ expects argument of type ‘float*’, but
         argument 3 has type ‘double*’ [-Wformat=]
```

Always and everywhere, turn on warnings (`-Wall -Wextra`) and do more error checking.

Anyway, to `fscanf` into a `double` you need `%lf` instead of `%f`.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. Yes, you are right, I just made the minor example and did not enable the flags.

Answer (score 2):

Given your input format...

```
1 ;2 ;3 ;4 ;5
```

...your code...

```
for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
    file >> *(A + N*c + r);
}
```

...will "eat" the first numeric value, then choke on the first `;` separator.  The simplest correction would be...

```
char expected_semicolon;

for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
    if (c) {
        file >> expected_semicolon;
        assert(expected_semicolon == ';'); // if care + #include <cassert>
    }
    file >> *(A + N*c + r);
}
```

---

For whatever it's worth, to add better error checking I'd suggest...

```
if (std::ifstream file(fname))
{
    ...use file stream...
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "oops\n";
    throw or exit(1);
}
```

...as a general practice for opening file stream.

For looping getting data, using a support macro to give an assertion-like style works well with streams:

```
#define CHECK(CONDITION, MESSAGE) \
    do { \
        if (!(CONDITION)) { \
            std::ostringstream oss; \
            oss << __FILE__ << ':' << __LINE __ \
                << " CHECK FAILED: " << #CONDITION \
                << "; " << MESSAGE; \
            throw std::runtime_error(oss.str()); \
    } while (false)

...

for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
    if (c)
        CHECK(file >> expected_semicolon &&
              expected_semicolon == ';',
              "values should be separated by semicolons");
    CHECK(file >> *(A + N*c + r), "expected a numeric value");
}
```

For this specific input parsing, for a production system you might want to use `getline` so you can know where you are in the input...

```
size_t lineNum = 0;
std::string my_string;
for (int r = 0; r < N; ++r) {
    CHECK(getline(file, my_string), "unexpect EOF in input");
    ++lineNum;
    std::istringstream iss(my_string);
        for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
            if (c)
                CHECK(file >> expected_semicolon &&
                      expected_semicolon == ';',
                      "unexpected char '" << c 
                      << "' when semicolon separator needed on line "
                      << lineNum);
            CHECK(iss >> *(A + N*c + r),
                  "non numeric value encountered on line " << lineNum);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: I agree Tony, however, the assert gets triggered, because you need `assert(expected_semicolon == ';');`, which should be part of the body of the if statement.

Comment: @gsamaras: damn,,, I often call such variables `c` - thought to change it because your code was already using `c`, but only in one place....  Good call on the need to keep the assert with the streaming too.... Cheers.

Comment: I jumped in and changed it before @TonyD's comment. Hope I didn't confuse things. Given the 9 minute delay, I assumed Tony had gone :-)

... and I didn't fix it up fully!

Comment: ... and I would add an `assert(file)` after every `>>` operation. And immediately after opening the file also. (Although, some would argue that `assert` is the wrong way to check this kind of error)

Comment: @AaronMcDaid appreciate your coverage! ;-)  Yeah... `assert` was just to draw attention to the possibility of verification, more than a recommendation over e.g. throwing.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: you've shamed me into a five minute brain-dump on error handling practice...!  Hope you can live with yourself ;-o.  Cheers.

Comment: Shouldn't `if(!CONDITION)` be `if(!(CONDITION))`?  ***:-)*** Sorry ***:-)***   I'm just worried about something like   `CHECK(getline(f,a) && getline(f,b))`

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: absolutely... I'm juggling too many things... well spotted again!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try getline(), which accepts a Delimiter as 3rd argument.

```
string buffer;
for (int c = 0; c < M; ++c) {
    getline(file, buffer, ';');
    stringstream tmp(buffer);
    tmp>>*(A + N*c + r);
}
```

getline() will read until the next delimiter or newline or end of file